# Acrobat Professional 11 extract all pages as jpegs without quality loss

Tags: pdf

In Adobe Acrobat professional 11 how can i export all the pages in a pdf file as single Jpeg images without losing quality?
I have a pdf with 140 pages but when i try the export function it makes 800 and more files because it export the several images he finds inside the page. What i want to do is that page 1 becomes a file named 1.jpg and so on.
Can it be done with adobe professional 11? I can do it in imagemagick, so it's not urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, unless the PDF document consists of images only, it is not possible to export as JPEG without quality loss, because JPEG **MEANS** quality loss (in photos, and there at places where it is not much noticed). JPEG is particularly bad when the image contains strong contrast, as you find with text, for example. In this case, it creates well visible artefacts, which make the image look "dirty". If you have to export PDF pages in a raster format, use a file format working with lossless compression, such as TIFF.

That said, to extract pages and save them as a raster image, you would use a two-step procedure. First step is extracting the pages from the document, second step is save those extracted pages in the raster format. Probably the easiest way to accomplish would be running the first step manually, and then set up an Action which saves all files within the folder as TIFF.

Comment: Thank you. So with Adobe I have to select every page and export it even if it's 150 pages?

Comment: With Adobe you have to watch out for the correct mud to straw mixture ratio. With Adobe Acrobat, you have get to the Extract Pages dialog, where you have the option to save each page as its own file.